# Countable nouns and uncountable nouns

Tags: grammar

To describe something with a noun that can have 2 different forms ( countable and uncountable)in the same meaning ,

Do I use the plural form or or uncountable

Eg The word " mist(N)"

(1) The hills were shrouded in mist

What case that  the word mist can be used as a countable noun ?

The sentence (1)  describes mist in general , why it can not be used as plural like other general case

E.g I use pencils to draw / I love watching movies

I"m sorry if my question is hard to understand

Comment: ***mist*** is like, for example, ***air***. We don't usually have any reason to refer to multiple mists or airs, the way we might count pencils, or compare movies.

Comment: Note that an artist might feasibly use ***pencil*** as a "non-count noun" - [*He uses pencil for his sketches*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22uses+pencil+for+his%22) Much depends on *exact* context, but there are few absolute rules. For example, it would be perfectly valid to use plural / countable ***pencils*** instead of singular / uncountable ***pencil*** in my "sketches" example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers While we don't usually have any reason to use plural mists, we [often do](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mist%2Cmists&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) in relative comparison to [how often we use "airs"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=air%2Cairs&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), which is almost never. I'm assuming this is the basis for the question. The OP knows this and wants to know when to choose "mists" over "mist".

Comment: @gotube: Your NGram doesn't really tell us much about plural "airs" relative to singular - we've no idea how many of the matches are *verb* contexts *(She **airs** the laundry)* or "false positive" plural nouns *(His **airs and graces** annoy me)*.  I'd have thought verb uses of ***mists*** would be much more common than ***to air***, but I suppose these days there might be quite a lot more instances of things like *The Simpsons Season 57 **airs** on Netflix next month*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, there's those usual faults, but a quick look at the books shows almost all of them are the plural of "mist", even after filtering out all the fantasy books with "Mists" in the title.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The word "airs" can also refer to a kind of music: "He played airs on an ancient theme" for example, or the well known "Air on the G String". Several such pieces would be "airs". One can also refer to "light airs from several directions" in a weather report. Still, "air" is rarely used in a plural form.

Answer (score 0):

the word "mist" could be used as a countable noun, to refer to mists in different places or different times. One might write, for example:

> There is one mist  over the land and another mist over the sea, and the two mists have different colors and seem quite different.

In that example, when the author refers to two different conditions, s/he writes "two mists" using a plural form, because in this usage the noun has become countablke.

Similarly, the word "sea" is usually a mass noun, that is, not countable. One refers to "the sea" in general. But when one refers to specific bodies of water, the word becomes countable, as in:

> The North and Caribbean seas are both adjcent to the Atlantic  Ocean.

Similarly, "gold" is normally an non-count noun, the name of a color or a metal. But when one specifies different types of gold, it becomes a countable noun, and a plural form may be used. For ecample:

> - There is a bright gold, and a duller gold, and gold hardly more than common yellow. All of theses golds may be useful to the painter.
> - The Jewelers of the middle ages distinguished between African gold, Indian gold, and ancient gold, treating theses different golds as different metals.